# Soup.find doesn't find the table I want to scrape with beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a data mining project, but the page I'm working with has an error in the data it offers to download, so I thought I'd scrape the page:
[Tabla de datos](https://www.gbif.org/occurrence/search?country=EC&country=PE&country=CO&country=BR&country=BO&country=CL&dataset_key=4fa7b334-ce0d-4e88-aaae-2e0c138d049e&has_coordinate=true&has_geospatial_issue=false&publishing_country=PE&publishing_country=EC&publishing_country=CO&publishing_country=BR&publishing_country=BO&publishing_country=CL&year=2016,2022&advanced=1)

I'm working with beautiful soup in Jupyter Notebook, the table doesn't have an id which is a problem for me, so I tried to extract it by class:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from datetime import datetime

url_page = 'https://www.gbif.org/occurrence/search?country=EC&country=PE&country=CO&country=BR&country=BO&country=CL&dataset_key=4fa7b334-ce0d-4e88-aaae-2e0c138d049e&has_coordinate=true&has_geospatial_issue=false&publishing_country=PE&publishing_country=EC&publishing_country=CO&publishing_country=BR&publishing_country=BO&publishing_country=CL&year=2016,2022&advanced=1'
page = requests.get(url_page).text 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
tabla = soup.find('table', {'class':'table search-table smaller'})
tabla
```

But it does not give me any results and then when I try to apply a soup.find it tells me that the object does not have said attribute

```
nombre_científico=""
país=""
Coordenadas=""
Mes_y_año=""
Base_del_registro=""
Conjunto_de_datos=""
Reino=""
Filo=""
Clase=""
Orden=""
Familia=""
Género=""
Especie=""
nroFila=0
for fila in tabla.find_all("tr"):
    if nroFila>=1:
        nroCelda=0
        for celda in fila.find_all('td'):
            if nroCelda==1:
                mc=celda.text
                print("nombre_científico:", nombre_científico)
            if nroCelda==2:
                score=celda.text
                print("país:", país)
            if nroCelda==3:
                puntos=celda.text
                print("Coordenadas:", Coordenadas)
            if nroCelda==4:
                puntos=celda.text
                print("Mes_y_año:", Mes_y_año)
            if nroCelda==5:
                puntos=celda.text
                print("Base_del_registro:", Base_del_registro)
            if nroCelda==6:
                puntos=celda.text
                print("Conjunto_de_datos:", Conjunto_de_datos)
            if nroCelda==7:
                puntos=celda.text
                print("Reino:", Reino)
            if nroCelda==8:
                puntos=celda.text
                print("Filo:", Filo)
            if nroCelda==9:
                puntos=celda.text
                print("Clase:", Clase)
            if nroCelda==10:
                puntos=celda.text
                print("Orden:", Orden)
            if nroCelda==11:
                puntos=celda.text
                print("Familia:", Familia)
            if nroCelda==12:
                puntos=celda.text
                print("Género:", Género)
            if nroCelda==13:
                puntos=celda.text
                print("Especie:", Especie)
            nroCelda=nroCelda+1
        with open('Pajaritos.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
                writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
                writer.writerow([mc,score,puntos])
    nroFila=nroFila+1
```

Can you help me grab the table please.

Comment: You need to learn about JavaScript. Turn it off and *see* what the site *really* looks like *in the eyes of bs4*.

Answer (score 0):

As stated it's javascript generated where the data is fetched from the api. The data comes at a max limit of 300 records per "page". So you could iterate through the offsets to gather the data. The downfall is there are 27,599,606, meaning at 300 per page is 91,999 pages to go through. now I'm not going to bombard the server for this, but that's up to you if you want to do it. But here's the first few rows would gets returned:

**Code:**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import math

url = 'https://www.gbif.org/api/occurrence/search'
limit = 300

payload = {
'advanced': 'true',
'country': ['EC','PE','CO','BR','BO','CL'],
'dataset_key': '4fa7b334-ce0d-4e88-aaae-2e0c138d049e',
'dwca_extension.facetLimit': '1000',
'facet': ['dataset_key','country'],
'facetMultiselect': 'true',
'has_coordinate': 'true',
'has_geospatial_issue': 'false',
'issue.facetLimit': '1000',
'locale': 'en',
'limit':f'{limit}',
'month.facetLimit': '12',
'offset': '0',
'publishing_country': ['PE','EC','CO','BR','BO','CL'],
'type_status.facetLimit': '1000',
'year': '2016,2022'}


totalCount = 99999
page = 0
total = 1

result = pd.DataFrame()
while page <= total:
    payload.update({'offset': f'{page * limit}'})
    jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
    totalCount = jsonData['count']
    total = math.ceil(totalCount / limit)
    
    print(f'Page: {page + 1} of {total}')

    result = pd.concat([result, pd.DataFrame(jsonData['results'])], axis=0)
    
    page += 1
```

**Output:**

```
print(result.head(5).to_string())
          key                            datasetKey                      publishingOrgKey                       installationKey publishingCountry     protocol                    lastCrawled                     lastParsed  crawlId                hostingOrganizationKey extensions      basisOfRecord  individualCount occurrenceStatus  taxonKey  kingdomKey  phylumKey  classKey  orderKey  familyKey  genusKey  speciesKey  acceptedTaxonKey                           scientificName                   acceptedScientificName   kingdom    phylum          order      family        genus                 species  genericName specificEpithet taxonRank taxonomicStatus iucnRedListCategory  decimalLongitude  decimalLatitude stateProvince  year  month  day            eventDate issues                lastInterpreted                                               license identifiers media facts relations                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           gadm                        institutionKey  isInCluster   recordedBy  inCluster geodeticDatum class countryCode recordedByIDs identifiedByIDs country     identifier  catalogNumber     vernacularName institutionCode    taxonConceptID                                                     locality      gbifID collectionCode                         occurrenceID                                   _datasetKey                        _publishingOrgKey                                                            _verbatimRecord county
0  3504143904  4fa7b334-ce0d-4e88-aaae-2e0c138d049e  e2e717bf-551a-4917-bdc9-4fa0f342c530  7182d304-b0a2-404b-baba-2086a325c221                BR  DWC_ARCHIVE  2022-03-02T17:41:33.833+00:00  2022-04-25T22:12:25.086+00:00       15  e2e717bf-551a-4917-bdc9-4fa0f342c530         {}  HUMAN_OBSERVATION              3.0          PRESENT   2488352           1         44       212       729       9352   2488348     2488352           2488352           Dacnis cayana (Linnaeus, 1766)           Dacnis cayana (Linnaeus, 1766)  Animalia  Chordata  Passeriformes  Thraupidae       Dacnis           Dacnis cayana       Dacnis          cayana   SPECIES        ACCEPTED                  LC        -49.004044       -14.605882         Goiás  2021      1    1  2021-01-01T00:00:00     []  2022-04-25T22:12:25.086+00:00  http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/legalcode          []    []    []        []  {'level0': {'gid': 'BRA', 'name': 'Brazil'}, 'level1': {'gid': 'BRA.9_1', 'name': 'Goiás'}, 'level2': {'gid': 'BRA.9.203_1', 'name': 'Santa Rita do Novo destino'}, 'level3': {'gid': 'BRA.9.203.1_1', 'name': 'Santa Rita do Novo destino'}}  8d313059-3f5e-411e-b176-6553050ff8c6        False   obsr921803      False         WGS84  Aves          BR            []              []  Brazil  OBS1040833643  OBS1040833643        Blue Dacnis             CLO  avibase-C72B6A62  Chácara Jayrson  Serra Da Mesa Goiás, BR (-14,606, -49,004)  3504143904          EBIRD  URN:catalog:CLO:EBIRD:OBS1040833643  {'title': 'EOD – eBird Observation Dataset'}  {'title': 'Cornell Lab of Ornithology'}           {'http://rs.tdwg.org/dwc/terms/scientificName': 'Dacnis cayana'}    NaN
1  3504143914  4fa7b334-ce0d-4e88-aaae-2e0c138d049e  e2e717bf-551a-4917-bdc9-4fa0f342c530  7182d304-b0a2-404b-baba-2086a325c221                BR  DWC_ARCHIVE  2022-03-02T17:41:33.833+00:00  2022-04-25T22:12:25.089+00:00       15  e2e717bf-551a-4917-bdc9-4fa0f342c530         {}  HUMAN_OBSERVATION              4.0          PRESENT   2495339           1         44       212      1446       5233   2495265     2495339           2495339  Patagioenas speciosa (J.F.Gmelin, 1789)  Patagioenas speciosa (J.F.Gmelin, 1789)  Animalia  Chordata  Columbiformes  Columbidae  Patagioenas    Patagioenas speciosa  Patagioenas        speciosa   SPECIES        ACCEPTED                  LC        -49.004044       -14.605882         Goiás  2021      1    1  2021-01-01T00:00:00     []  2022-04-25T22:12:25.089+00:00  http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/legalcode          []    []    []        []  {'level0': {'gid': 'BRA', 'name': 'Brazil'}, 'level1': {'gid': 'BRA.9_1', 'name': 'Goiás'}, 'level2': {'gid': 'BRA.9.203_1', 'name': 'Santa Rita do Novo destino'}, 'level3': {'gid': 'BRA.9.203.1_1', 'name': 'Santa Rita do Novo destino'}}  8d313059-3f5e-411e-b176-6553050ff8c6        False   obsr921803      False         WGS84  Aves          BR            []              []  Brazil  OBS1040838549  OBS1040838549      Scaled Pigeon             CLO  avibase-3EAF0903  Chácara Jayrson  Serra Da Mesa Goiás, BR (-14,606, -49,004)  3504143914          EBIRD  URN:catalog:CLO:EBIRD:OBS1040838549  {'title': 'EOD – eBird Observation Dataset'}  {'title': 'Cornell Lab of Ornithology'}    {'http://rs.tdwg.org/dwc/terms/scientificName': 'Patagioenas speciosa'}    NaN
2  3504143936  4fa7b334-ce0d-4e88-aaae-2e0c138d049e  e2e717bf-551a-4917-bdc9-4fa0f342c530  7182d304-b0a2-404b-baba-2086a325c221                BR  DWC_ARCHIVE  2022-03-02T17:41:33.833+00:00  2022-04-25T22:12:25.096+00:00       15  e2e717bf-551a-4917-bdc9-4fa0f342c530         {}  HUMAN_OBSERVATION              1.0          PRESENT   2484386           1         44       212       729       6176   2484385     2484386           2484386      Molothrus oryzivorus (Gmelin, 1788)      Molothrus oryzivorus (Gmelin, 1788)  Animalia  Chordata  Passeriformes   Icteridae    Molothrus    Molothrus oryzivorus    Molothrus      oryzivorus   SPECIES        ACCEPTED                  LC        -50.069880        -6.069878          Pará  2021      1    1  2021-01-01T00:00:00     []  2022-04-25T22:12:25.096+00:00  http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/legalcode          []    []    []        []                                {'level0': {'gid': 'BRA', 'name': 'Brazil'}, 'level1': {'gid': 'BRA.14_1', 'name': 'Pará'}, 'level2': {'gid': 'BRA.14.90_1', 'name': 'Parauapebas'}, 'level3': {'gid': 'BRA.14.90.1_1', 'name': 'Parauapebas'}}  8d313059-3f5e-411e-b176-6553050ff8c6         True   obsr623443       True         WGS84  Aves          BR            []              []  Brazil  OBS1040854136  OBS1040854136      Giant Cowbird             CLO  avibase-91375A56                             Home Guama 95 (-6,0699,-50,0699)  3504143936          EBIRD  URN:catalog:CLO:EBIRD:OBS1040854136  {'title': 'EOD – eBird Observation Dataset'}  {'title': 'Cornell Lab of Ornithology'}    {'http://rs.tdwg.org/dwc/terms/scientificName': 'Molothrus oryzivorus'}    NaN
3  3504143940  4fa7b334-ce0d-4e88-aaae-2e0c138d049e  e2e717bf-551a-4917-bdc9-4fa0f342c530  7182d304-b0a2-404b-baba-2086a325c221                BR  DWC_ARCHIVE  2022-03-02T17:41:33.833+00:00  2022-04-25T22:12:25.096+00:00       15  e2e717bf-551a-4917-bdc9-4fa0f342c530         {}  HUMAN_OBSERVATION              5.0          PRESENT   5229662           1         44       212       729       5291   2483336     5229662           5229662    Tyrannus melancholicus Vieillot, 1819    Tyrannus melancholicus Vieillot, 1819  Animalia  Chordata  Passeriformes  Tyrannidae     Tyrannus  Tyrannus melancholicus     Tyrannus   melancholicus   SPECIES        ACCEPTED                  LC        -46.532104       -23.657183     São Paulo  2021      1    1  2021-01-01T00:00:00     []  2022-04-25T22:12:25.096+00:00  http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/legalcode          []    []    []        []                         {'level0': {'gid': 'BRA', 'name': 'Brazil'}, 'level1': {'gid': 'BRA.25_1', 'name': 'São Paulo'}, 'level2': {'gid': 'BRA.25.537_1', 'name': 'Santo André'}, 'level3': {'gid': 'BRA.25.537.3_1', 'name': 'Santo André'}}  8d313059-3f5e-411e-b176-6553050ff8c6        False   obsr853065      False         WGS84  Aves          BR            []              []  Brazil  OBS1040855522  OBS1040855522  Tropical Kingbird             CLO  avibase-BB6B236F                            Santo André--Prefeitura Municipal  3504143940          EBIRD  URN:catalog:CLO:EBIRD:OBS1040855522  {'title': 'EOD – eBird Observation Dataset'}  {'title': 'Cornell Lab of Ornithology'}  {'http://rs.tdwg.org/dwc/terms/scientificName': 'Tyrannus melancholicus'}    NaN
4  3504144076  4fa7b334-ce0d-4e88-aaae-2e0c138d049e  e2e717bf-551a-4917-bdc9-4fa0f342c530  7182d304-b0a2-404b-baba-2086a325c221                BR  DWC_ARCHIVE  2022-03-02T17:41:33.833+00:00  2022-04-25T22:12:25.148+00:00       15  e2e717bf-551a-4917-bdc9-4fa0f342c530         {}  HUMAN_OBSERVATION              1.0          PRESENT   2493744           1         44       212       729       5232   2493743     2493744           2493744        Coereba flaveola (Linnaeus, 1758)        Coereba flaveola (Linnaeus, 1758)  Animalia  Chordata  Passeriformes  Coerebidae      Coereba        Coereba flaveola      Coereba        flaveola   SPECIES        ACCEPTED                  LC        -46.974483       -22.948578     São Paulo  2021      1    1  2021-01-01T00:00:00     []  2022-04-25T22:12:25.148+00:00  http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/legalcode          []    []    []        []                               {'level0': {'gid': 'BRA', 'name': 'Brazil'}, 'level1': {'gid': 'BRA.25_1', 'name': 'São Paulo'}, 'level2': {'gid': 'BRA.25.631_1', 'name': 'Valinhos'}, 'level3': {'gid': 'BRA.25.631.1_1', 'name': 'Valinhos'}}  8d313059-3f5e-411e-b176-6553050ff8c6        False  obsr1601789      False         WGS84  Aves          BR            []              []  Brazil  OBS1040947746  OBS1040947746         Bananaquit             CLO  avibase-B78F2D6F                   Valinhos--Rua Benedito Jesuino de Oliveira  3504144076          EBIRD  URN:catalog:CLO:EBIRD:OBS1040947746  {'title': 'EOD – eBird Observation Dataset'}  {'title': 'Cornell Lab of Ornithology'}        {'http://rs.tdwg.org/dwc/terms/scientificName': 'Coereba flaveola'}    NaN
```